# Spark : Creating Object RDD from List<Object> RDD

Tags: java, apache-spark, rdd

Assume `Employee` is a Java Class.

I have a `JavaRDD<Employee[]> arrayOfEmpList`, i.e, each RDD has an `array of employees`.

Out of this, I want to create a single list of employees, something like

```
JavaRDD<Employee>
```

This is what i tried:
Created a `List<Employee> empList  = new ArrayList<Employee>();`

then foreach RDD of Employee[]:

```
arrayOfEmpList.forEach(new VoidFunction<Employee[]>(){
public void call(Employee[] arg0){
   empList.addAll(Arrays.asList(arg0));
   System.out.println(empList.size()); //prints correct values incrementally
}
});

System.out.println(empList.size()); //gives 0
```

I am not able to get the size outside foreach loop.

Is there some other way to achieve this?

P.S: i want to have all employee records as separate RDD, so 1st employee list may contain 10 records, 2nd may contain 100 records, 3rd may contain 200 records. i want a final list of 330 records, which i can then parallelize and perform actions upon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is the `flatMap` transformation on your array. I'm first converting your employee array into a list:

```
JavaRDD<Employee> employeeRDD = arrayOfEmployeeList.flatMap(empArray -> Arrays.asList(empArray));
```

*Check, perhaps the method has an overload that takes an array directly, not just a collection.*

You can see this in the transformations section of the programming guide: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#transformations

JavaDocs: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/api/java/JavaRDDLike.html#flatMap(org.apache.spark.api.java.function.FlatMapFunction)